# How to set Windows 10 default narrator to 32 bit

Tags: windows-10-v2004, narrator

I was wondering if there is a solution to use 32 bit narrator as default in Windows 10 (2004 update). I am searching for an answer to this because I have 32 bit SAPI 5 voices installed and they do not show in the default system settings.